# How Can i set TimeInterval as a xAxis Label in Core plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, graph

I want to display time formant on xAxis label in core plot. How can i set that ? I show an Example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729366/moving-date-on-x-axis)

but that time didn't show on Xaxis but if i mantion Date on xAxis DD:MM:YY format then it did show so what i change in that link code so it will work fine ?
Thanks

Comment: Bittu, instead of asking every single thing you want to do here. You are free to look at the documentation. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/w/list or http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html?name=release_1.0 For date formatters start here; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: hi you can get reference from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876884/how-to-plot-months-of-the-year-on-x-axis-using-core-plot-in-iphone/10877508#10877508